# How to do a pattern match on a certain decimal pattern

Tags: c++, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to perform a pattern match in C++ where the format is...

```
  ###.######## (example input would be 135.123551235)
```

I have tried the following pattern but it won't match with the data I have inputted...

```
  // get the points entered
  getline(cin, x1ANDy1);

  regex r("([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)", regex_constants::basic);
  if (regex_match(x1ANDy1, r))
  {
      cout << "Data has been entered properly.";
  }
  else
  {
      cout << "Data has been entered in the improper format, please re-enter your data.";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern would be "\d{3}.\d{9}" for exact 3 digits dot(.) 9 digits or "\d{lowerbound, upperbound}.\d{lowerbound,upperbound}" if you want to allow certain digit amounts. Or replace the curly braces with * if you dont want to limit it.